# Regular expression for extracting element from MDX Query

Tags: regex, mdx

I would like to extract information, or the query axis element from a given MDX query.
Suppose I have this query :

```
SELECT NON EMPTY {
    Hierarchize({[Product].[Product Family].Members})
} ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY Hierarchize ( 
    Union ( 
        CrossJoin ( {[Time].[1997].[Q1]}, 
            CrossJoin ([Store].[Store Name].Members, 
                [Store Type].[Store Type].Members
            )
        ), 
        CrossJoin({[Time].[1997].[Q2]}, 
            CrossJoin([Store].[Store Name].Members, 
                [Store Type].[Store Type].Members
            )
        )
    )
) ON ROWS FROM [Sales] 
WHERE {
    Hierarchize({[Measures].[Unit Sales]})
}
```

The substring I would like to extract has pattern like this :
[...](.[...]) or
[...].[...].Members

Note that, ... means any alphanumeric, and what inside bracket means can be recurred.
Thus, the results I expect are :

> [Product].[Product Family].Members; [Time].[1997].[Q1];
>   [Time].[1997].[Q2]; [Store].[Store Name].Members; [Store Type].[Store
>   Type].Members; [Measure].[Unit Sales]

I tried my best and finally figured this regex :

```
\[.*?[A-Za-z\s]\](.*?(\.\[.*?[A-Za-z\s]\])|(\.Members))
```

But the results are :

> [Product].[Product Family]; [Time].[1997].[Q1]}, CrossJoin ([Store];
>   [Store Name].Members, [Store Type].[Store Type]; [Time].[1997].[Q2]},
>   CrossJoin([Store]; [Store Name].Members, [Store Type].[Store Type];
>   [Sales] WHERE {Hierarchize({[Measures].[Unit Sales]

Can someone give any correction with my regex?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm, could you try this:

```
(\[[\w ]+\]\.\[[\w ]+\](?:\.(?:Members|\[Q\d\]))?)
```

This seems to work for me. I tried it on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/UToQ4mX94E).

Comment: @Jerry Much better solution than mine. Good job.

Comment: @DHN: Thanks! Took quite some trial and error before getting it though ^^;

Comment: `\w\d` the `\d` is redundant because digits are included in `\w`

Comment: @Roland That's a really old answer xD Didn't know that much back then. Fixed now + improved

Answer (score 1):

Interesting task...

Well please try the following
`(?<result>\[[^\]]+\]\.\[[^\]]+\]\.Members)|(?<result>(\[[^\]]+\]\.){2}\[[^\]]+\])`

if you read the group `result` in every match you will get, what you want. I used [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) to construct the `RegEx`.

Comment: Thank you very much! However, the regex didn't work well here. I used [Pattern](https://itunes.apple.com/id/app/id429449079?mt=12) to test the regex. Perhaps there are misstyping or something like that happened?