# Parsing DAX Query with Regular expression to get measures and dimensions

Tags: regex, mdx, dax, azure-analysis-services

I want to create an application that uses Extended Events to analyze the usage of Azure Analysis Services models. 
Specifically, I want to know what measures and dimensions the end users are using.

I look at the QueryEnd event and try to parse the TextData field. Depending on the tool used for querying the model I get either MDX or DAX in the TextData.

I think I have managed to parse the MDX with this RegEx: ([[\w ]+].[[\w ]+](?:.(?:Members|[Q\d]))?)
(from this post: [Regular expression for extracting element from MDX Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864454/regular-expression-for-extracting-element-from-mdx-query))

Now parsing the DAX is the problem. If I query the model from fx PowerBI I get a DAX like this:

```
EVALUATE 
TOPN(
502,
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
ROLLUPADDISSUBTOTAL('Product'[Color], \"IsGrandTotalRowTotal\"),
\"Order_Count\", 'SalesOrderDetail'[Order Count]
),
[IsGrandTotalRowTotal],
0,
[Order_Count],
0,
'Product'[Color],
1
)
ORDER BY
[IsGrandTotalRowTotal] DESC, [Order_Count] DESC, 'Product'[Color]
```

What I would like to match with the RegEx is:

'Product'[Color] and 'SalesOrderDetail'[Order Count]

And.... how would i know that Order Count is used as a measyre while Color is an attribute of the Product dimension?..... guess I won't?

Thanx a lot
Nicolaj

Answer (score 0):

think I just found a possible solution for parsing both DAX and MDX queries:

```
([\[\'][\w ]+[\]\']\.?[\[\'][\w ]+[\]\'])(?!.*\1)
```

This will give me what I need.... without duplicates. Improvements are welcomed :-)

Answer (score 0):

For disambiguating columns from measures, I would query the DMVs for the deployed model to get a list of columns and a list of measures. Then you can just look up your parsed tokens in the two lists:

[DMV docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/use-dynamic-management-views-dmvs-to-monitor-analysis-services)

[Column DMV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sql_server_protocols/ms-ssas-t/c6fdd3e5-47f0-41f6-89ca-0336465c631d)

[Measure DMV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sql_server_protocols/ms-ssas-t/960d4f92-49e9-4231-a39f-c7048e4ea63d).

Note that measure names are globally unique among the population of column and measure names, so that is an easy lookup (just throw away the table reference). Column names are only unique within the table they belong to.

It looks like you've already got a regex that's working for you, so run with that.

I'll also note that almost all PBI visuals which are returning anything other than a simple list (e.g. slicers or one column tables will return just a list) will follow the pattern of the query you shared.

Measures should all be in later args to `SUMMARIZECOLUMNS`. The pattern is:

```
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    <grouping columns, optionally in a ROLLUPADDISSUBTOTAL>,
    <filters, defined above in VARs>,
    <measures as ("Alias", [Measure]) pairs>
)
```